# How to distinguish Office 2016, 2019 and 365

Tags: c#, office365, ms-office, office-interop

I'm developing a VSTO Add-in and I have an issue. I got the Office version number from the registry but the number is 16.0, and I know Office 2016, 2019, and 365 share the same version number.

How to distinguish the three Office versions? I'm using C# but would appreciate any way of solving this question.

```
_officeVersions.Add("7.0", "Office97");
_officeVersions.Add("8.0", "Office98");
_officeVersions.Add("9.0", "Office2000");
_officeVersions.Add("10.0", "OfficeXP");
_officeVersions.Add("11.0", "Office2003");
_officeVersions.Add("12.0", "Office2007");
_officeVersions.Add("14.0", "Office2010");
_officeVersions.Add("15.0", "Office2013");
_officeVersions.Add("16.0", "Office2016");
```

Comment: You're going to need the full build number which consists of four parts 16.0.x.y to distinguish between the different Office versions from 2016 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

That's where the bits like build numbers after `16.0` play a vital role.

You can use the [Update history for Office 2016 C2R and Office 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019) and [Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date) for identifying the exact Office version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact context, but if you can get the `Process` object corresponding to the Office process you are running inside, you can look it up from the main module's file info. Here's some sample code which assumes your add-in is for Excel:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel").Single();
var version = process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
```

`version` now contains a string which can be looked up for [Office 2016/2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019) or separately for [Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date).